# Block all urls on windows desktop using win32 API

Tags: windows, winapi, url, desktop-application, blocking

I am trying to develop one application which can block all urls using win32 api on windows desktop application.
So is there any api or any procedure doing programmatically so that i can block all urls?

Comment: just to clarify - desktop application will display some URLs but you want your users to be prohibited from visiting these sites when clicking on these links?

Comment: Please explain what "blocking a URL" means. Say I have blocked "file:///C:/autoexec.bat", what does that mean?

Comment: Depending on the "depth" of your interception or the scope of what you're trying to do, you can try user-mode hooking or Firewall API. E.g: all the IE infrastructure (I don´t know about Edge) is based on WININET API.If you hook the entrypoints and inject the hook in the applications you want, you could implement restrictions at URL level. You can even use CBT Hooks to inject all binaries. This of course, wont stop Firefox or Chrome or other browsers accessing the URL, only WININET-based ones. The same concept with hooking Winsock at user-level.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to block just URLs. If you want to make sure no one can access the internet the only way to do this would be to unplug the ethernet cable. (Or whatever is giving you connectivity) Here's why:

1. Blocking all DNS resolution won't stop someone from accessing http://206.132.84.265/
2. Blocking port 80 and 443 won't stop someone from accessing a web site hosted on a non-standard port.
3. Denying access to IE and installation of any other software won't stop someone from downloading a browser that doesn't require to be installed (Like a text browser) and putting it on a thumb drive.
4. Buying an expensive firewall that blocks HTTP traffic won't be able to stop SSL operating on a non-standard port.

Believe me, back in highschool I worked in a warehouse with a scanner gun and figured out how I could check my email with it (with a little help from my computer at home) since an internet gateway was on the same network.

If you want to block people from surfing the web, disconnect the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Windows Firewall Protocol. This is an API provided by Microsoft.

For Vista it's straight-forward, but for XP you need to do some work around, as examples are not available for that.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do it using the Windows Firewall API

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa366453.aspx